# Arduino error message that I don't understand

Tags: library, sketch

I downloaded Arduino code from this: https://github.com/BabyWrassler/MissionControl/ Github, and got the  error message below.

It is designed to work with a Raspberry Pi, and I installed the two Adafruit libraries.  I also have not hooked it up to either the Pi, or the two Adafruit devices, but that is partly because I cannot get it to run without the error message.

Update:
Here is what was highlighted: 
`Adafruit_LEDBackpack matrixA = Adafruit_LEDBackpack();`
The orange bar says:
    Variable or field ‘matrixOff‘ declared void
I cannot tell what of the following was from before, but here is the entire console log:

```
    mcDesk.ino:2:53: error: Adafruit_LEDBackpack.h: No such file or directory
    mcDesk.ino:3:45: error: Adafruit_GFX.h: No such file or directory
    mcDesk:11: error: variable or field 'matrixOff' declared void
    mcDesk:11: error: 'Adafruit_LEDBackpack' was not declared in this scope
    mcDesk:11: error: expected primary-expression before 'buffer'
    mcDesk:12: error: variable or field 'ledOn' declared void
    mcDesk:12: error: 'Adafruit_LEDBackpack' was not declared in this scope
    mcDesk:12: error: expected primary-expression before 'buffer'
    mcDesk:12: error: expected primary-expression before 'cat'
    mcDesk:12: error: expected primary-expression before 'an'
    mcDesk:13: error: variable or field 'ledOff' declared void
    mcDesk:13: error: 'Adafruit_LEDBackpack' was not declared in this scope
    mcDesk:13: error: expected primary-expression before 'buffer'
    mcDesk:13: error: expected primary-expression before 'cat'
    mcDesk:13: error: expected primary-expression before 'an'
    mcDesk:14: error: variable or field 'dispMat' declared void
    mcDesk:14: error: 'Adafruit_LEDBackpack' was not declared in this scope
    mcDesk:14: error: expected primary-expression before 'buffer'
    mcDesk:17: error: variable or field 'threeDigitDisp' declared void
    mcDesk:17: error: 'Adafruit_LEDBackpack' was not declared in this scope
    mcDesk:17: error: expected primary-expression before 'buffer'
    mcDesk:17: error: expected primary-expression before 'cats'
    mcDesk:17: error: expected primary-expression before 'ans'
    mcDesk:17: error: expected primary-expression before 'number'
    mcDesk:18: error: variable or field 'digitDisp' declared void
    mcDesk:18: error: 'Adafruit_LEDBackpack' was not declared in this scope
    mcDesk:18: error: expected primary-expression before 'buffer'
    mcDesk:18: error: expected primary-expression before 'pos'
    mcDesk:18: error: expected primary-expression before 'cat'
    mcDesk:18: error: expected primary-expression before 'an'
    mcDesk:18: error: expected primary-expression before 'num'
    mcDesk:23: error: variable or field 'switchBars' declared void
    mcDesk:23: error: 'Adafruit_LEDBackpack' was not declared in this scope
    mcDesk:23: error: expected primary-expression before 'buffer'
    mcDesk:23: error: expected primary-expression before 'grphCats'
    mcDesk:23: error: expected primary-expression before 'grphAns'
    mcDesk:23: error: expected primary-expression before 'cmnd'
    mcDesk:23: error: expected primary-expression before 'offset'
    mcDesk:24: error: variable or field 'barDisp' declared void
    mcDesk:24: error: 'Adafruit_LEDBackpack' was not declared in this scope
    mcDesk:24: error: expected primary-expression before 'buffer'
    mcDesk:24: error: expected primary-expression before 'grphCats'
    mcDesk:24: error: expected primary-expression before 'grphAns'
    mcDesk:24: error: expected primary-expression before 'pos'
    mcDesk:24: error: expected primary-expression before 'offset'
    mcDesk:25: error: variable or field 'cBarDisp' declared void
    mcDesk:25: error: 'Adafruit_LEDBackpack' was not declared in this scope
    mcDesk:25: error: expected primary-expression before 'buffer'
    mcDesk:25: error: expected primary-expression before 'grphCats'
    mcDesk:25: error: expected primary-expression before 'grphAns'
    mcDesk:25: error: expected primary-expression before 'pos'
    mcDesk:25: error: expected primary-expression before 'offset'
    mcDesk:11: error: 'Adafruit_LEDBackpack' does not name a type
    mcDesk:12: error: 'Adafruit_LEDBackpack' does not name a type
    mcDesk:13: error: 'Adafruit_LEDBackpack' does not name a type
    mcDesk:14: error: 'Adafruit_LEDBackpack' does not name a type
    mcDesk:15: error: 'Adafruit_LEDBackpack' does not name a type
    mcDesk.ino: In function 'void decodeCommand()':
    mcDesk:193: error: 'matrixE' was not declared in this scope
    mcDesk:193: error: 'ledOn' was not declared in this scope
    mcDesk:199: error: 'matrixE' was not declared in this scope
    mcDesk:199: error: 'ledOff' was not declared in this scope
    mcDesk:204: error: 'matrixC' was not declared in this scope
    mcDesk:204: error: 'cBarDisp' was not declared in this scope
    mcDesk.ino: In function 'void allMatrixOff()':
    mcDesk:213: error: 'matrixA' was not declared in this scope
    mcDesk:213: error: 'matrixOff' was not declared in this scope
    mcDesk:214: error: 'matrixB' was not declared in this scope
    mcDesk:215: error: 'matrixC' was not declared in this scope
    mcDesk:216: error: 'matrixD' was not declared in this scope
    mcDesk:217: error: 'matrixE' was not declared in this scope
    mcDesk.ino: At global scope:
    mcDesk:220: error: variable or field 'matrixOff' declared void
    mcDesk:220: error: 'Adafruit_LEDBackpack' was not declared in this scope
    mcDesk:220: error: expected primary-expression before 'buffer'
```

Comment: "`Adafruit_LEDBackpack` not declared" tells me maybe the library wasn't installed? Can you run one of the examples in that library? (File > Examples)

Comment: @sachleen which one?  Does it matter?

Comment: Printscreen is far clearer than taking a picture of the screen. Also put all of your code up on pastebin.

Comment: @cybergibbons sorry, I was using my iPad to make the post.  My Arduino computer doesn't have wifi on it.

Comment: Copy and paste the messages from the text below the code window, as well as the code section that has the error in it (the highlighted section). Try not to post images of code or error messages, when it is in plain text.

Comment: Don't use images to explain your problem. Nobody is ever going to find this question through a search engine because the text cannot be indexed and it uses much more resources than necessary. What is wrong with a regular copy and paste of the text?

Comment: It's hard because I don't have my Arduino computer connected to the internet. 

Comment: Ok I figured out how to copy and paste it.   Adding all the spaces before each line took FOREVER but it is all on there now.

Comment: Those error messages are exactly the ones I get when the libraries aren't there and they go when the library is there.

Comment: The first 2 lines clearly show that you have not properly installed the 2 required adafruit libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that those Adafruit libraries were not correctly installed on your PC or your sketch.

In addition to downloading and installing the library onto the Arduino library directory (on Windows, that's normally `C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Arduino\libraries`), when you want to use that library with Arduino IDE, you must add the library for your sketch with the menu command "**Sketch -> Import Library...**"

**Important note**: it seems just adding `#include "library.h"` does not work with Arduino IDE, you absolutely need to use the menu.

Comment: I don't think I've ever used the menu to include a library - it definitely works just typing it in here.

Comment: @Cybergibbons I faced that problem a couple of times in the past (I almost never use Arduino IDE anymore though, except for quick qnd dirty proofs of concept), that's why I mentioned it here.

Comment: Interesting. The more I use the Arduino IDE, the more I dislike it.

Comment: I tried that, but still got the exact same error message. @cybergibbons + jfproilpret

Comment: I agree with Cybergibbons, you don't *have* to use the menu...

Comment: Installing external libraries can be a mess, I suggest trying [biicode](https://www.biicode.com/) ([docs](http://docs.biicode.com/arduino.html)) that downloads and configures them for you. Your required libraries are here:  [adafruit](https://www.biicode.com/adafruit) and the firmware is here [mission control](https://www.biicode.com/babywrassler/blocks/babywrassler/missioncontrol/branches/master#.Uybheq15NOY) you can try with `bii open babywrassler/missioncontrol` to download it along with adafruit requirements